# select and accept delay in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select

I created a simple application to accept IPv4 TCP connections using select() and accept().

I use a python script to test this. It opens 100 connection in sequence. ie:

```
for i in range(100):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print s.connect((IP, PORT))
    s.send("Test\r\n")
```

What I observe is that my application gets stuck in select() for 2 seconds after the first X connections.
Output from strace:

```
1344391414.452208 select(30, [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29], NULL, NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
1344391416.742843 accept(3, 0, NULL)    = 30
```

My code is following. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int
fd_create (void)
{
    int fd;
    int set = true;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &set, sizeof(set));

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1999);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(fd, 1024);

    return (fd);
}

int
fd_echo (int fd)
{
    int n;
    char buffer[128 + 1];

    while ((n = recv(fd, buffer, 128, 0)) > 0);

    return (n);
}

int
main (void)
{
    int listen_fd;
    fd_set working;
    fd_set master;
    int max_fd;
    int i;
    int new_fd;
    int rc;
    int con;

    FD_ZERO(&master);
    listen_fd = fd_create();
    fcntl(listen_fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(listen_fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    max_fd = listen_fd;
    printf("%d\n", listen_fd);
    FD_SET(listen_fd, &master);
    con = 0;
    for (;;) {
    memcpy(&working, &master, sizeof(fd_set));
    select(max_fd + 1, &working, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i <= max_fd; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &working)) {
        if (i == listen_fd) {
            while ((new_fd = accept(i, NULL, NULL)) >= 0) {
            fcntl(new_fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(new_fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
            FD_SET(new_fd, &master);
            if (max_fd < new_fd) {
                max_fd = new_fd;
            }
            printf("New connection %d (%d)\n", new_fd, ++con);
            }
            if ((new_fd == -1) && (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)) {
            return(0);
            }
        } else {
            rc = fd_echo(i);
            if ((rc == 0) ||
            ((rc == -1) && ((errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)))) {
            close(i);
            FD_CLR(i, &master);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that your script was generating connections during those two seconds?

Comment: Your fd_echo() method doesn't compile. What does the real code look like?

Comment: user315052. Good question! Actually it doesn't generate connections. As the connections are made in sequence. I guess the connection either fails to connect() or connect() with the 2 sec latency.

Comment: EJP. Sorry some error during copy pasting I guess. fixed it.

Comment: Actually this is not Linux specific. Happens in sun/solaris as well.

Comment: You should not really loop sockets from 0 to `max_fd`, since you don't really know what values the sockets have you could be looping thousands of times just for a few sockets. It's better to have a simple linked list of all connections, and iterate only over that.

Comment: Also, your "client" doesn't close its connections. It just opens them, send some data, and the make a new connection. This can put some strain on the system, although it shouldn't be that bad. By the way, does `X`differ a lot? What else is your computer doing when it happens?

Comment: Joachim, your remarks on the first note are fair, but remember that this is a test app to verify what I see in my application is not due to some bug there. Yes the idea is to bombard the server with 1000 connections and keep them open until all of them are open. I don't think 1000 connection are that much. Nothing else is running on the system. Load is around 0.01 or something.

Comment: OK. So the exact same code works fine with poll(). I.e. I don't see the delay. My wild guess is that there must be a window where data have arrive on a socket but select was not updated or something.

Comment: And if in the echo function we send back what we received everything works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE/WARNING:** while trying to prove this answer applies, I found that maybe it doesn't. I ran the test and got delays without max_fd ever getting higher than 300. And I got delays with poll() too. So I tried tcpdump and there were retransmissions. It looks like even 127.0.0.1 can drop packets when you throw them at it this fast. Leaving the answer here because it is a real issue, even if it's not the most pressing one.

So this involves a lot of file descriptors, and it works with poll but not select. With those clues I can see the explanation: you've gone over the `FD_SETSIZE` limit.

The official pronouncement from POSIX is (referring to `FD_ZERO`/`FD_SET`/`FD_CLR`/`FD_ISSET`):

> The behavior of these macros is undefined if the fd argument is less than 0 or greater than or equal to FD_SETSIZE, or if fd is not a valid file descriptor, or if any of the arguments are expressions with side-effects.

(from 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html)

To really understand what happened you have to look deeper than the official specification into the actual implementation of the `fd_set` type. It has a split personality. In the kernel, where `select` is implemented, it's treated as a variable-length array of bits. The first argument to `select` is used to decide where the array ends. If you call `select(2048, ...)` the kernel will expect each non-NULL `fd_set *` to point to an array of 256 bytes (2048 bits).

But in userspace, `fd_set` is a fixed-size struct. The size is `FD_SETSIZE` bits, which is 1024 on my system and probably yours too. `FD_SET` and the other macros are basically just doing assignments to elements of the array, only they're a little more complicated because they have to deal with the conceptual array elements being the individual bits. So if one of your file descriptors is 1024 and you try to `FD_SET` it, you've done the equivalent of

```
int array[1024];
array[1024] = 1;
```

In other words, you clobbered whatever was in memory after the `fd_set`, causing weird things to happen later.

There are ways around this. I've seen old code that does a `#define FD_SETSIZE somebignumber` before including the header that defines `fd_set`. I don't know what OSes that worked on; I just tried it and glibc seems to ignore it.

A better possibility is to do something like the old "struct hack" where you'd allocate a struct with more memory than its `sizeof`, and the extra memory would be usable as extra elements in the array that was the last member of the struct.

```
fd_set *rfds = malloc(128+sizeof *foo); /* can hold fds up to FD_SETSIZE+128*8-1 */
```

Now of course you need to remember to free it when you're done with it, and pass `rfds` instead of `&rfds` to `select` and the `FD_*` macros, and do your own `memset` instead of `FD_ZERO`, and hope that the kernel implementation doesn't change since you're now *real* chummy with it. But it works... for now.

Using poll is actually probably the correct answer.

Comment: I did make sure I never go above the 1024 limit in my tests. In fact I never used more than 1000 connections. I think your update is right. Must be a packet rate-limiting or something. Today I cannot reproduce not even with select() so maybe the statement that it works with poll() was not 100% right.

Comment: Ahh.. I think your update explains the situation perfectly. I.e. the SYN packet gets dropped by the kernel, the application sleeps on select, then the retransmission of the SYN comes in (after 2 sec?) and the application wakes up. Good one! Thanks!

Comment: You are right: "# netstat -s | grep drop" gives "187 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped". I wonder however why are they getting dropped...

Comment: Running systemtap and the dropwatch script it seems that the packets are dropped in "tcp_v4_do_rcv()". Inside that function they are most likely dropped at "struct sock *nsk = tcp_v4_hnd_req(sk, skb);" "if (!nsk)" "goto discard;". So probablye tcp_v4_hnd_req() fails?

Comment: OK Final update... Sorry for spamming. Verified now that the same behavior is seen in FreeBSD as well. God knows what I am doing wrong with such a few lines of code :-)

Answer (score 1):

So further debugging of the kernel...

The packet gets dropped in "tcp_v4_syn_recv_sock()" because "sk_acceptq_is_full(sk)" returns true.

"sk->sk_ack_backlog" is 11 and the configured "sk->sk_max_ack_backlog" is 10. (We set this in the listen() command.)

(Updating based on EJP notes.)
So I guess what is happening is:

Client blocks on connect(). A SYN is sent to the server. Kernel gets the SYN sends SYN/ACK. Client gets back the SYN/ACK and unblocks and a) sends the ACK and b) a new SYN/ACK.

Server receives the ACK and puts the connection in the backlog.

Do that 10 times and we are stuck.

Good one guys. Wouldn't have understand it without your help. Thanks!!

Comment: That's easy. In blocking mode, connect() sends a SYN, waits for a SYN/ACK, sends an ACK, and returns. In non-blocking mode the connect() behaviour may be different, and I defy you to find a document anywhere that specifies it. At the server, the SYN is received and the SYN/ACK is sent, a half-formed socket is placed on a queue, and when the ACK arrives it is moved from there to the backlog queue. Meanwhile accept() essentially blocks on the backlog queue, or in non-blocking mode select() returns if a selectable listening socket has items in the backlog queue.